# Should the two CW's about photography gifts between $0-100 be merged?

Tags: discussion, status-completed

I'm talking about [these](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/5046/what-are-good-gifts-between-50-and-100-for-photographers) [two](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/3067/what-is-a-cheap-less-than-usd50-piece-of-kit-would-make-a-good-gift-for-a-phot) questions.

They are nearly the same and have some very similar answers.

Comment: I've locked them. As it stands, we've long since decided that these are examples of bad questions for the site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well... they do have different price ranges, but I think they're better off locked as historical interest rather than merged.

Comment: Agreed. Let's lock em.

Comment: @jrista - Done.